# Removing an invalid escape sequence from a Java String

Tags: java

I have an invalid escape sequence inside a json string.  The sequence is:

> 'ngram': "'s\xa0cancer prevention"

I have been trying to remove this sequence completely by replacing it with a blank string, however each attempt fails.  I have tried the following ways:

```
qumlsOutputAsJson = qumlsOutputAsJson.replaceAll("[^\\x20-\\x7E]", "");
```

and

```
qumlsOutputAsJson = qumlsOutputAsJson.replaceAll("\\.", "");
```

and even a routine:

```
    private String removeNonAscii(String text){
    String asciiText = "";
    for (char aChar: text.toCharArray()){
        if((int)aChar<=0x7F)
            asciiText = asciiText + Character.toString(aChar);
    }
    return asciiText;
}
```

All have failed.

I'm sure there is an obvious way, but any direction much appreciated.

Comment: I added an answer but I had misread your question. What's your expected output?

Comment: A line of code to remove the offending invalid escape sequence. But it can't be specific to the line I gave, just a generic piece of code to remove invalid escape sequences from the string

Comment: Regex requires two backslashes to represent one, because a backslash is *also* an escape sequence in regex. `qumlsOutputAsJson = qumlsOutputAsJson.replaceAll("[^\\\\x20-\\\\x7E]", "");`

Comment: Pardon my sleepy brain, but in your example, what should the output be?

Comment: No worries. The output should be: 'ngram': "'sxa0cancer prevention" or even 'ngram': "'sa0cancer prevention". Anything to remove the offending escape sequence

Comment: See my answer so, hopefully it helps :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `replaceAll` you need to escape the backslash, i.e. `"\\\\",""`

If you just used `replace`, yours should work as expected

```
qumlsOutputAsJson = qumlsOutputAsJson.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```